# Why am i getting a ModuleNotFoundError when i add rest_framework to my django app

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pipenv

I created a new django app and installed djangorestframework using pipenv version 2020.11.15 and regestered it in the settings.py file

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'leads',
    'rest_framework'
]
```

i got this error on running `python manage.py makemigrations`

```
C:\Users\eliHeist\Python Workspace\lead_manager_react_django\leadmanager>python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\eliHeist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in
execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\eliHeist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in
execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\eliHeist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\eliHeist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\eliHeist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 224, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\eliHeist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework'
```

What is going on?

Comment: Follow the docs https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the packages installed in your virtual environment using

```sh
$ pip freeze
```

if you can't find the **"djangorestframework"** package in the list, then its not installed, install django rest framework by `$ pip install djangorestframework`

It looks like you are using **pipenv** for the virtual environment,

Activate the virtual environment in the project folder by using

```sh
$ pipenv shell
```

and install the required packages, i.e django, djangorestframework etc.. like

```sh
$ pipenv install djangorestframework
```

Use `$ pipenv install {package-name}` if you are using pipenv.

Comment: Thanks virtual environment was not activated